# Drawing complex roots with Table[Graphics[]]

Tags: graphics, complex, drawing

I'm trying to plot roots of a complex equation and have succeeded with drawing vectors to each root. Now I want to draw the heptagon from each root to the next, but I cannot figure out how to do this. Here is my code:

```
In: cn = z /. Solve[z^7 == 1 - I]
Out: //array of solutions

In: cnpp = N[Table[{Re[cn[[i]]], Im[cn[[i]]]}, {i, 1, 7}]]
Out: //array of pairs to plot

In: Show[ListPlot[cnpp, AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}, AspectRatio -> 
    Automatic, PlotMarkers -> Automatic], 
    Table[Graphics[{Thick, Red, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Re[cn[[i]]], Im[cn[[i]]]}}]}], {i, 1, 7}]]
Out://plot of vectors
```

Next I tried

```
Show[ListPlot[cnpp, AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotMarkers -> Automatic], 
    Table[Graphics[{Thick, Red, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Re[cn[[i]]], Im[cn[[i]]]}}]}], {i, 1, 7}], 
    Table[Graphics[{Thick, Blue, 
    Line[{{Re[cn[[i]]], Im[cn[[i]]]}, {Re[cn[[i + 1]]], 
    Im[cn[[i + 1]]]}}]}], {i, 1, 6}]]
```

Which gives me
[image]

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the solutions are not sorted in the order you expect.

Try doing ``.

```
cn = z /. Solve[z^7 == 1 - I] // SortBy[N@*Arg];
```

The first plot is unchanged, but the second one makes a nice hexagon, less one missing leg:

```
Show[ListPlot[cnpp, AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotMarkers -> Automatic], 
    Table[Graphics[{Thick, Red, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Re[cn[[i]]], Im[cn[[i]]]}}]}], {i, 1, 7}], 
    Table[Graphics[{Thick, Blue, 
    Line[{{Re[cn[[i]]], Im[cn[[i]]]}, {Re[cn[[i + 1]]], 
    Im[cn[[i + 1]]]}}]}], {i, 1, 6}]]
```

> [image: hexagon missing one edge]

Note that you also need to add a segment to close the hexagon.

Answer (score 1):

As @jjc385 already noted, the crux of the matter is that you have to sort the roots in order of increasing (or decreasing) argument.

It also simplifies matters if you avoid forming a `Table`, since you already have the roots in a list.

What I want to point out here is how annoying it seems, after you get complex numbers as the roots, to have to pull those complex numbers apart into their real and complex parts before plotting them. David Park's *Presentations* add-on allows you to plot complex numbers without doing that.

```
<<Presentations`

With[{seventhRoots = z /. Solve[z^7 == 1 - I, z]},
   pts = SortBy[seventhRoots, N@Arg[#] &];
   Draw2D[
     {
      Legacy@IndianRed, PointSize[Large], ComplexPoint /@ pts,
      Blue, Thick, ComplexLine[Append[pts, First@pts]],
      Red, Thick, ComplexArrow[{0, #}] & /@ pts
     }, 
   Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"},
   PlotLabel -> Style["Roots of z^7 = 1-I", 14, Bold]]
  ]
```

[image: Plot of 7th roots of 1 - I]

I really wish devoutly that *Mathematica* would add complex graphics objects, such as the *Presentations* addon's `ComplexPoint`, `ComplexLine`, and `ComplexArrow`, just as it already has as primitives complex numbers themselves. Doing graphics with complex numbers would be *so* much more direct then.

(end proselytizing)